# Попрепятствовать распознователю голоса распозновать голос

Tags: android, voice-recognition, распознавание-речи

Я разрабатываю приложение с таким юз-кейсом:

Пользователь смотрит видео. В процессе просмотра пользователь может отдавать голосовые команды, которые распознаются приложением.

Проблема состоит в том, что во время проигрывания видео идет звук, который теретически может содержать голосовую команду.

Есть ли способ помешать распознавателю голоса распознать аудио-поток таким образом, чтобы юзер не заметил различий между обычным звуком и измененным?

Какой-нибудь аудио-канал там испортить или типо того (ничего не понимаю в обработке звука).

Для проигрывания видео я использую ExoPlayer от Google

Для распознания голоса я использую SpeechKit от Яндекса https://tech.yandex.ru/speechkit/mobilesdk/

PS я готов отказаться от SpeechKit в пользу другой технологии, если это решит мою проблему

Comment: Тут скорее надо смотреть в сторону активного шумоподавления. Т.е. телефон знает, какой звук идет на динамики и должен вычитать его из микрофонного входа.

Comment: И как вычитать его, этот звук? Я просто не понимаю ничего в обработке звука

Comment: Боюсь тут надо обращаться на узкопрофессиональные ресурсы, либо к знакомым гуру (ну или работать с заказчиком в направлении, что "этот кейс будет стоит 100500 денег, вы согласны?")